# Configuing Spring boot OAuth2 behind a reverse proxy with rewrite path

Tags: spring-boot

How to configure Spring Boot for OAuth2 security behind a reverse proxy which rewrites the path?

For instance https://outside.example.com/my-app -> https://inside.example.com:8080/

This is very common when working with Docker container which typically are designed to run in the "/" context path.

Spring boot supports x-forwarded headers so the first step is to add the following line to the configuration file:
`server.forward-headers-strategy=FRAMEWORK`

Without path rewrite, that would be it. But how to do with path rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot can also use `X-Forwarded-Prefix` header. This is a header that is not supported by a lot of proxies, so make sure you set it manually.

For instance with Apache, it would look like something like this:

```
<Location /my-app>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Prefix" expr=/my-app
  </Location>
```

The second thing is to make sure that your web framework is configured to use relative path. For instance with VueJS, make sure to set the following in vue.config.js:
`publicPath: ''`

That's it!